# Inverse function in R

Tags: r, inverse

So I have a function: `f(a,b,rho)=r`. Given `a`,`b` and `r`, I would like to find `rho`. I came across the inverse function in R, but it seems that when the function tries to find `rho`, the function cannot tell which of `a`, `b` or `rho` is the specified `rho` and also the function cannot load the given `a` and `b`. In addition, I know that `rho` will be between 0 and 1.

```
a = -.7
b = 2
r <- function(rho,a,b){
            # basically here I defined a very long function of r 
            # in terms of a and b and rho
     }

R_inverse=inverse(function(rho) r(rho,-.7,2),0,1)

# r_value is just a random value
R_inverse(r_value)
```

This does not work. I would appreciate any help with the inverse function or any other alternative way to find `rho` given `r` and `a` and `b`.

Comment: Where did you find the `inverse` function? It's not in the default packages.

Comment: You could maybe treat it as a 1-dimensional optimization problem, see `?optimize`. Is `r` a smooth function of `rho`? Do you know that there is a unique solution?

Comment: You could use a root finding function for solving `f(a,b,rho)-r = 0`. Create a function `g(rho) = f(a,b,rho)-r` and let for example the base R function `uniroot` find a solution for `g(rho)=0`. There are other packages and functions that could help. See the Numerical Mathematics page in Task Views on CRAN.

Comment: @Bhas thanks! I used uniroot and it solved my problem.